# replace part of a string in java

Tags: java, string, text, char

I'm trying to write a function which takes in a string such as `String code = "<div> style="width: 3%" </div>"`

I would like to replace the 3% to another number (can be more than 2 digits) so 400% etc.

I'm currently getting the charAt(21) but this is only the index of 3, so if I had 20% in that place then my code would not work.

Is there another way to replace the place where the % is stored. (also doing this by not knowing what number the current % is)

Comment: Pick up your phone and call regular expressions.

Comment: I'm just wondering why are you doing this in Java since manipulating DOM elements should be handled differently

Comment: @Lucas I believe it's for some sort of self-made CMS

Comment: Why do this in Java, not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a regular expression, for example:

```
String code = "<div> style=\"width: 3%\" </div>"
String replaced = code.replaceFirst("width: \\d+", "width: 400")
```

To extract the value in the existing string:

```
Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("width: (\\d+?)%");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(code);
matcher.find()
matcher.group(1)//Gives 3
```

Comment: would it be possible to get the current % in code using \d?

Comment: Have extended my answer to cover that

Comment: Thank you, your solution is exactly what I was looking for. I cannot up vote unfortunately.

Comment: Just one more thing. matcher.group(1) does return 3 for the use case, however what if I have 30% instead of 3%, it will still only return the first digit which is 3, but I would want the whole number 30.

Comment: Yes I have and I can only seem to get the first number so 3 if its 30%, or 4 if its 44%.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be using HTML parser. But if your string will always be simple, you can use `replaceAll` which takes a regex:

```
String code = "<div> style=\"width: 3%\" </div>";
String res = code.replaceAll(yourRegex, replacement);
```

I will leave the full solution for you, but will give you few hints:

- [Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- `\d+` will match digits, so `width:\s+\d+` will match "width" followed by space(s) and then digit(s)
- Use parenthesis to group the caught result from the regex, for example `width:\s+(\d+)` will catch the result of the digits (group)

Answer (score 0):

If your String it's:

```
String code = "<div> style="width: 3%" </div>"
```

You can find the position in which the `%` it's stored, like this:

```
int position = code.indexOf("%");
```

And suppossing that you have your number stored in a String:

```
String number = "2";
```

**Note:** It doesn't matter if it is `2` or `22` or `222`.

You can get the total `String` with `substring` function:

```
String totalString = code.substring(0,position - 1) + number + code.substring(position+1, code.length());
```

And now you can print it normally:

```
System.out.println(totalString);
```

I expect it will works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use String#replaceFirst or String#replaceAll method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

```
code = code.replaceFirst("width: ?(.*)%", "width: 400%");
```

Of course adapt the regex to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML parser such as [Jsoup.](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)